# Older LG phone worked fine before update, after update, phone wont turn on, black screen

Tags: updates, lg

My most recent phone broke, so I was going to use my older LG phone (LGLS755, or LG X power) with a mobile hotspot checked out from a library to get by until I get a new phone.  This older phone was working fine this morning and was at around 74% battery after charging overnight.  A strange thing, the charging didn't seem to go above 74%.  Not sure if this is related to the problem or not.

Well at the library, I plugged the phone into a USB of the PC and connected to the library's WiFi.  Again the phone was running fine.  I saw an option to do an Android update, so I went ahead and did that.  I didn't really pay attention to it, but after a bit I looked at the phone and the screen was black.  I took out the USB cord and reinserted it and didn't notice anything.  I tried doing a normal on button, nothing happened.  I did an on / volume down buttons combination and nothing.  On the desktop PC connected to the phone, in an "other devices" section, the phone just appears as "USB Serial Device (COM4)".

I took off the back of the case, and on the back of the battery was a piece of white tape saying something like "Battery is not intended to be removed, do not remove or serious injury could result".  So I put the back of the case on.

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could help me getting this phone running again.

Comment: Installing an update on an old phone that is not connected to a real charger is always a bad idea. Firmware updates do stress the battery and stressing old batteries can cause a voltage drop so that the device crashes. If this happens while installing the firmware bad things can happen.